# Accessing the daemon from remote server

Tags: docker

I am trying to access the dockerd daemon from a remote machine via tcp.

I will say first that I am aware of the security risk on non encrypted and will look to move but cant get this working.

I have setup things as best I can but cannot seem to connect from a remote machine.

I have the following in my daemon.json file

```
{
  "hosts": ["tcp://172.16.16.62:2375", "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"]
}
```

I can see that it is listening on the correct port in netstat

```
tcp        0      0 hostname:2375 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

I can even connect to it from the local host

```
docker -H tcp://172.16.16.62:2375 ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                 COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                          NAMES
ddc2e3f97067        Image   "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"   3 days ago          Up 27 minutes       0.0.0.0:2200->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4400->8000/tcp   epic_lamarr
7867cd6193df        Image2   "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"   7 days ago          Up 27 minutes       0.0.0.0:2201->22/tcp                           competent_brahmagupta
```

But from a remote host I get

```
docker -H tcp://172.16.16.62:2375 ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://172.16.16.62:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I can confirm that the traffic is getting there.

```
sudo tcpdump -ni any  port 2375 -s 0 
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
08:35:06.451656 IP 172.16.16.61.48096 > 172.16.16.62.2375: Flags [S], seq 3191742733, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1080792310 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
08:35:06.452992 IP 172.16.16.61.48098 > 172.16.16.62.2375: Flags [S], seq 4090360, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1080792312 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

I cannot seem to understand why this is not responding.

Comment: 172.16.x.x is a private IP range. Can you ping this IP from your remote machine? (same private network).

Comment: yep, as you can see from the tcpdump I can access from one to the other on the correct port, so there is no firewall in the way either

Comment: True, and maybe a stupid remark but did you reload and restart your docker daemon

Comment: yeah, I have tried a few restarts, including changing the port to 2376, I know that this is convention for the encrypted port but am clutching at straws now.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with tcpdump but I assume that telnet 172.1616.61 2375 from the other instance will also work. I tried it once too (without 2376/ssl stuff) and it worked for me without specific different configurations than you've explained

Comment: yeah they will kinda test the same thing, the tcpdump is capturing the packets from the actual application, so this proves that the packets are getting from one server to the other, this should do the same thing as the telnet test, also the fact that I can connect from the local server to the docker instance on the tcp port using the -H flag should indicate the service is listening correctly.